# VBA code multiple if condition and put complete datein respective column

Tags: vba

I am creating macro and I am stuck in creating the main page of VBA code. we have a sheet named "Renewal" in which all the customer information we dump. Column C we have customer number, Column D We have product type Dental, LIFE & Dis. Column A we have to put complete data, and Column B we have to put annual premium. Now I want the main page where I can one input box1 in which I put customer number,  combo box1 in which 3 option I will get "DENTAL, LIFE, DIS., input box2 Date of completion, and input box3 annual premium. If input box1 and combo box1 condition satisfy then date will put on same row of column A and annual premium in column B respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question was very interesting, maybe a screenshot might be better. Ok this is what I have crafted. I am sorry I am not sure this code will work 100% as I have not got Word installed on this machine so had to write it in notepad, so may not be the best solution. As suggested in one of the comments - you have to add add() in the button1_click event. Hopefully this has been of some use.

```
Private Sub add()                   'Add the add sub routine to the button1_click
    Sheets("Renewal").Activate()            'makes the sheet activate
    if textbox1.text <> "" and textbox2.text <> "" and textbox3.text <> "" and combobox1.text <> "" then        'condition
        dim pos as integer          'used to find next position
        pos = findNext()            'adds next position value

        activesheet.cells(1,pos).value = textbox2.text          'adds Date of completion
        activesheet.cells(2,pos).value = textbox3.text          'adds annual premium
        activesheet.cells(3,pos).value = textbox1.text          'adds customer number
        activesheet.cells(4,pos).value = combobox1.text         'adds product type

        'unsure if combobox1.text is correct.

    end if                      'end of the condition
End sub                         'end of sub routine

Private function findNext()                 'this function finds the next position in sheet
    dim x as integer                'used as a counter
    x = 1                       'counter = 1
    do                      'start of iteration
        x = x + 1               'counting
    loop until activesheet.cells(1,x).value = ""    'end when cell (A, counter) has no value
    return x                    'returns the counter value
End function                        'end of function
```

P.S. If you are a complete begin beginner - This video may help you with the ui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCIpMwdKCgE